# Joomla 1.5! Page class suffix does not work correctly with other menu modules

Tags: joomla, menu, superfish

Width this code:

```
<?php
  $menus      = &JSite::getMenu();
  $menu      = $menus->getActive();
  $pageclass   = ""; 
  if (is_object( $menu )) :
  $params = new JParameter( $menu->params );
  $pageclass = $params->get( 'pageclass_sfx' );
  endif; 
?>
```

We can use **$pageclass** in body tag to style pages. But for me, this code works fine only for **mod_mainmenu**. If you use , for example, **Superfish** or **Extended Menu** modules "page class suffix" works only for first menu element (Home or else).

Is there any solution? Please, help...

Comment: Can you link an example? The page class suffix should be completely independent of the modules on the page.

Answer (score 0):

'Page class suffix' is different for different languages. I use Joomfish. In my translation there is no 'page class suffix' for other language. This is the answer. I am happy!